# Chemfig: align all letters (atoms) on a line

Tags: chemfig

How to align all letters (atoms) on one line in the following example

```
 \documentclass{standalone}
 \usepackage{chemfig}
 \begin{document}
 \chemfig{\lewis{35,O}=C=\lewis{2,N}-[,1.5]{{(CH_2)}_2}-[,1.5]C-\lewis{2,N}=C=\lewis{17,O}}
 \end{document}
```

The C-atom of the CH2 and the follwong C are "too high".

Comment: Please have a look at part III (Advanced usage) section 4 (Vertical alignment) of the current [`chemfig` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf).

Comment: I read the section now, but I can't adjust for my problem: I don't understand why the C of CH_2 is too high? Then I tried to adjust the single C - which is overnext to the N with \chemfig{\lewis{35,O}=C=\lewis{2,N}-[,1.5]{{(CH_2)}_2}-[,1.5]{\vphantom{\lewis{2,N}}C}-\lewis{2,N}=C=\lewis{17,O}} but it does not work

Answer (score 2):

## The Why

The problem here is well documented in the `chemfig` manual, under the part on Advanced usage, section 4 (Vertical alignment). This alignment problem arises as the atoms in each group are aligned such that their baseline is in line with the baseline of the preceding group (note: singular).

Suppose we have a group with lower baseline (resulting from a subscript, as in the case of `CH2_2`). The next `C` will attain a `vphantom` command, and is thus raised above all others. but not to subsequent groups (the `N=C=O` on the right side).

[image: without]

## The How

To fix it, you *could* add `vphantom`'s all round to the other atoms which are not getting "raised". But in your case, since you only have one group that is causing the problem (namely, the `(CH2)_2` group), you can assign the command `\chemskipalign` before the offending group to stop `chemfig` from assigning the `vphantom` to the `C` right after the `(CH2)_2` group. Then it will align properly again, like so:

[image: with]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \fboxsep=0pt    
    \renewcommand\printatom[1]{\fbox{\ensuremath{\mathrm#1}}}   % Show bounding boxes to see the \vphantom at work; 

    Without \verb!\chemskipalign!:\par\medskip
    \chemfig{\lewis{35,O}=C=\lewis{2,N}-[,1.5]{(CH_2)_2}-[,1.5]C-\lewis{2,N}=C=\lewis{17,O}}

    \bigskip

    With \verb!\chemskipalign!:\par\medskip
    \chemfig{\lewis{35,O}=C=\lewis{2,N}-[,1.5]{\chemskipalign(CH_2)_2}-[,1.5]C-\lewis{2,N}=C=\lewis{17,O}}
\end{document}
```

**Note on code:**

- I added in bounding boxes with `\fbox` (from the `chemfig` documentation) so you can see the `\vphantom` at work, and what difference the `\chemskipalign` command does to it. No need to include this in your actual code.

### Final output:

[image: final]